# How can I remove the seconds from a date and time represented in milliseconds from the Unix epoch in .NET?

Tags: c#, java, .net, datetime

In Java, I'd do this (note that it is returning the date and time in milliseconds from the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) as well):

```
private static long removeSeconds(long timestamp)
{
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

How can I implement this in `.NET`?

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, assuming you want the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, but with the seconds removed, I'd do the following:

```
private static readonly GregorianCalendar DefaultGregorianCalendar = 
    new GregorianCalendar();

private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = 
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, DefaultGregorianCalendar);

private static long RemoveSeconds(long timestamp)
{
    // Convert the timestamp into a DateTime.
    var dt = DefaultGregorianCalendar.AddMilliseconds(UnixEpoch, timestamp);

    // Get the time in minutes.  The zero has the effect of removing the
    // seconds component.
    var newTime = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0, 
        DefaultGregorianCalendar);

    // Subtract the epoch from the new time.
    TimeSpan difference = newTime - dt;

    // Return the total milliseconds.
    return (long) difference.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Of note:

- The [`GregorianCalendar` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.aspx) is used to preserve your explicit usage of Java's [`GregorianCalendar` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)
- Java's [`getTimeInMillis` method on the `Calendar` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29) returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch; .NET doesn't have an equivalent, but it does return the number of nanoseconds from January 1, 0001 through the [`Ticks` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx).  This is utilized in order to convert to/from nanoseconds.
- When creating the new [`DateTime` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) from milliseconds, removing the seconds component is as easy as passing 0 to the new instance that represents `timestamp`.
- Once the [difference between the two dates is obtained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx), getting that in milliseconds is easy through the [TotalMilliseconds property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) on the [`TimeSpan` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577.aspx)